# Combining two lines with BASH Scripts

Tags: linux, bash, vim, fedora

I am using vim to make a simple script trying get the output of lm_sensors into another file. My problem is the formatting that needs to be done with requires combining two lines and outputting them into a file. Here is what I have currently:

```
LINE1=(echo -en System: INFO $(date +%x) $(date +%T) : CPU Temperature \{ ; sensors| grep Core\ sed 's/        /, /g'|tr -d '\n')
LINE2=(echo -e \})
echo $LINE1$LINE2 >> (FILE PATH)
```

LINE2's sole purpose is to put a } bracket at the end of the data, so if there is a better way to do that all in one line I am all ears.

Disregarding the sed and tr commands which format the data, I would like the output data to look as follows, though I always get an 'unexpected token ';'' error message with the above script.

`System: INFO (date time) : CPU Temperature { CPU Temp DATA }`

I greatly appreciate all input.

Comment: why don't you put the brace into the string directly? Why this strange indirection via `LINE2`?

Comment: I have tried to put it after the tr command, though all that does is get rid of all the data in between the two }'s. That's why I had to add LINE2. If you can show me the correct way to stick it at the end so I wouldn't have to use variables, problem solved.

Comment: put it into the line with the `echo`? I.e. `echo "$LINE1\}" >> (FILE PATH)` or what am I missing?

Comment: after doing that I still get: `syntax error near unexpected token ';'`

Comment: It's too hard to post code in comments. See my answer. We can work there to try and figure it out. I also suggest that you use a variable in place of `(FILE PATH)` for now, so that we can be certain about correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, perhaps:

```
LINE1=`echo -en System: INFO $(date +%x) $(date +%T) : CPU Temperature \{ ; sensors| grep Core\ sed 's/        /, /g'|tr -d '\n'`
echo "$LINE1\}" >> (FILE PATH)
```

Alternatively:

```
(echo -en System: INFO $(date +%x) $(date +%T) : CPU Temperature \{ ; sensors| grep Core\ sed 's/        /, /g'|tr -d '\n')|while read line; do
   echo "$LINE1\}" >> (FILE PATH)
done
```

Comment: I used your first option and everything was golden. Apparently it was the parentheses that were screwing everything up. I really appreciate the help, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: @Dbonuccelli: Glad I could help. You also used the backticks in the wrong places, I would say. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

It can be a lot tidier:

```
temp=$(sensors | awk '/Core/ {printf("%s%s", sep, $3); sep = ", "}'; echo "")
printf "System: INFO %s : CPU Temperature { %s }\n" "$(date "+%x %T")" "$temp"
```

Comment: Hehe, the beauty of Bash and Perl. One problem and a hundred different ways to solve it :) ... +1 from me.